# Searching strings in C# - ignore x

Tags: c#, windows, string, forms, search

I wish to create a program for my business.

I will have a set of data, such as

```
Post to:
FirstName LastName
Their Address
Their Address
Australia

MORE RANDOM WORDS/DATA (such as the item they ordered)
```

What I wish to do is create a string of everything between "Post to:" and "Australia". How would I go about doing this as I would have maybe 30 customers and that means 30 (Post to:) and (Australia). I wish to take each of these and separate them to eventually copy them to the clipboard.

I will be using a windows form for this.

EDIT: I think creating a method which returns data from an array would do this. How would i do the searching though.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply split based on Post to & then you'll get an array of items + australia + what you're not interested in
Then as a second step on all elements i'd split on " " and do a takeuntil it matches australia which gives you what you want but as a sequence of words
As a last step you'd then recombine those strings, all of this is pretty inefficient but for the little amount of data you mention it will be plenty fast & very easy to write / maintain.

Here's some pseudocode

```
var s = file.ReadToEnd(yourfile);
s.Split(new string[]{"Post to"}) // Split on post to to get an array of string with 1 string per customer
     .Select(item=>item.Split(new char[]{' '}) // split on each word so that we can find australia
           .TakeUntill(substring => substring == "Australia") // take all the words untill we find australia, then stop
           .Aggregate((a,b)=>a+" " + b)// rebuild the string by summing all those words preceeding australia
           );
```

Comment: Would this keep the formatting (such as a new line between "Post to" and FirstName?

Comment: Yes as we're not touching them, it however would remove multiple " " together as it removes all white space occurrence and only adds one whitespace back afterward so for example "test (many whitespace here) string" would become "test string" (just edited this as the comment doesn't allow multiple spaces either)

Comment: Thanks :) However, when I loop this after getting the first set of data, how do I ignore the first set and "capture" the second set?

Comment: i'm not sure about what you mean, if your question is about how you get the 2nd 3rd etc customers, the code already does it, this codes gives you an array of strings that have the content you wanted pretty much. (untested)

Comment: Oh right, I see it now. I'll give this a go and let you know, thanks for the help, too!

Comment: Leave your email in comment & i'll contact you if you want a quote for help on your project.